# How to convert Rich web application to Mobile ( Oracle Jdeveloper)?

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, hybrid-mobile-app

We are currently developing an Rich Web Applications With Oracle ADF (JDeveloper).
Is there a way we could wrap the web application and deploy it into mobile appl (ios and andriod) ?

If not, is there any alternative you guys may suggest to us?

Programming lanugage : Java

Database : Oracle DB / Microsoft SQL

Appreciate your help ! :D

Comment: I have written quite a few apps for iOS and android with an oracle backend.   I would no longer write an app using a wrapper.  However, the short answer is you can do it on android, and on iOS only with care.   Imagine there is no network connectivity, you must still have an interface and working app.   So the wrapper becomes important.  With that said, I find it worth the while to have native apps that call oracle via rest APIs, built in node.   That native look and feel and responsiveness is expected in an app.

Answer (score 0):

You could rebuild parts of your application in Oracle MAF. But that will take 'some' time.

You can make your current application responsive and use an WebView for Android (I don't know the iOS/Windows equivalents) to display your web application.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your respond.  I will also like to check if , working on the Oracle MAF first, will there be a possibility to deploy/repackage it to be an webapp?

Comment: No, Oracle MAF only generates to a native application (.ipa and/or .apk)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle MAF as a wrapper and use its remote URL feature pointing to your Web app. This will basically display the ADF content inside the MAF application on the device.

Comment: Hi shay, any example I can take a look and see how it works ?